# RabbitMQ - Message remains unacked, connections silently killed

Tags: c#, .net, process, rabbitmq

I have a very simple client that I want to be available 24/7 to consume messages. It is running in a Windows process.

I have no issues with the server and receiving messages, it is just the client.

The behavior is as follows:

Works if I start the connection fresh. After some time, perhaps hours, my client is in an odd state; the connection it contains 'holds' unacked messages.

In other words, using the web admin interface, I see that I have a total of, say, 2 unacked messages. Looking at my connections, I see the 2 unacked messages spread out.

But there is no processing going on.

And eventually, my connections get killed, with **no exceptions or log messages** being triggered. This puts all the messages into the ready state.

My first attempt to solve the problem was to add a simple external loop that checked the state of the i-vars of IModel, IChannel, and QueueingBasicConsumer. However, IModel/IChannel's IsOpen always reports true, even after the web admin reports no connections are active, and QueueingBasicConsumer's IsRunning always reports true as well.

Clearly I need another method to check whether a connection is 'active'.

So to summarize, things work well initially. Eventually, I get into an odd state where my diagnostic checks are meaningless, and messages sent to the server get unacked, and are spread out across any existing connections. Soon, my connections are killed with no debugs or exceptions thrown, and my diagnostic checks still report things are kosher.

Any help or best practices would be appreciated. I have read up on heartbeat, and the IsOpen 'race' condition, where it is suggested to use BasicQos and check for an exception, however I want to first understand what is happening.

Here is where I kick things off:

```
private void StartMessageLoop(string uri, string queueName) {
    this.serverUri = uri;
    this.queueName = queueName;

    Connect(uri);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> MessageLoopTask(queueName));
}
```

Here is how I connect:

```
private void Connect(string serverAddress) {
    ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();

    cf.Uri = serverAddress;

    this.connection = cf.CreateConnection();

    this.connection.ConnectionShutdown += new ConnectionShutdownEventHandler(LogConnClose);
    this.channel = this.connection.CreateModel();
}
```

Here is where the infinite loop starts:

```
private void MessageLoopTask(string queueName) {
    consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
    String consumerTag = channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);

    while (true) {
        try {       
            BasicDeliverEventArgs e = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
            IBasicProperties props = e.BasicProperties;
            byte[] body = e.Body;       

            string messageContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            bool result = this.messageProcessor.ProcessMessage(messageContent);

            if(result){
                channel.BasicAck(e.DeliveryTag, false);
            }
            else{
                channel.BasicNack(e.DeliveryTag, false, true);
                // log
            }
        }
        catch (OperationInterruptedException ex) {
            // log
            break;
        }    
        catch(Exception e) {            
            // log      
            break;
        }
    }
    // log
}
```

Regards,
Dane